# R - Can't customize values of cuts when plotting points with spplot

Tags: r, plot, customization, shapefile

I am using **spplot** to plot a shapefile. I need to give a different color to each point of the shapefile according to its attribute value.

My shapefile attribute table looks like this:
[Attribute_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMgnD.png). I have to plot points according to the value of Fall, Winter, Spring and Summer (in total I have 4 plots, 1 for each season).

By running this code (**r_values** is my shapefile):

```
# Defining point size
point_size = 0.8

# Defining where cuts are
classes_R = seq(-1,1,0.05)

# Defining color of scale bar
my.palette_R = brewer.pal(n = 10, name = "RdBu")

spplot(r_values, zcol = c("Fall","Winter","Spring","Summer"), do.log = F,as.table = T,
   pch = 20, cex = point_size, key.space = "right", col.regions = my.palette_R,
   main = "R Values - P Model", colorkey = T, at=classes_R,
   sp.layout=(list(new_layer_1,new_layer_2))) #sp.layout is for 2 other layers (you can see the states in gray and the lakes in blue in backround
```

I obtain this plot: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPrpk.png).

Changing the cuts(the classes) in classes_R doesn't change the resulting plot.

What I would like to obtain is a map with cuts ranging from -1 to +1 every 0.05 and labels on the right of the scale bar with these cuts.

Here is a link to download an excel file with some data. It's a dataframe containing the coordinates of the points

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WPyS5TFGCxBDNhJIJc_jKvFmJd5hthl4

Comment: can you please provide access to a small test data set so that we can reproduce your code? Also, if you want cuts by 0.05 with a range of 2, you'll need 40 colors. Have a look [here](http://www.nickeubank.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/RGIS3_MakingMaps_part1_mappingVectorData.html#controlling-color-breaks) and [here](http://rspatial.r-forge.r-project.org/gallery/) to see if it answers your question.

Comment: @Kamil I added an excel file with some data and the coordinates of each point

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the R documentation of "ssplot". It says:

> cuts: number of cuts, or, for objects of class SpatialPointsDataFrame only, the actual cuts to use

So in this case "cuts" is not an integer indicating the number of cuts, but it's a vector containing the actual cuts to use.

I changed the code using the option "cuts" instead of "at" and it worked.